# node ejs function a script on click

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, function

I have a simple function using a graph api and I want to run it when the user pushes a button. The file I am running from is a ejs file with a header and footer as a prefix and suffix to the code.

**My code is below:**

```js
<%- include("./partials/header")%>
<script type="text/javascript" src ="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="<%Functions.common1()%>">Click me</button>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="300"></canvas>

<button onclick="<%Functions.common1()%>">Graph me</button>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
<%- include("./partials/footer")%>
```

I have a function called common1 which is an exported function in another file called functions which simply console.logs a string. I wish to run the entire script to run the graph on the click of a button, **how do I do this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't trigger server-side code directly from client-side code.

When the page is requested from the server:

1. The EJS template will be executed
2. `<%Functions.common1()%>` will be evaluated (you say it simply logs a string, so it will do that on the server's console at this time)
3. The result (including `onclick=""` because `<%Functions.common1()%>` doesn't output anything to the template) will be sent to the browser.
4. Clicking will do nothing because the `onclick` function body is empty

---

If you want to execute `common1()` on the server when the button is clicked, then you need to write a webservice that will do it and then trigger it with an HTTP request (e.g. using `fetch` from the `onclick` function).

If you want to execute `common1()` on the browser when the button is clicked, then you will need to include it in the page using a `<script>` element, and putting the function call directly in the `onclick` function (i.e. not inside EJS tags).

---

And if you want run the code that generates the graph on a click, then put *that* in a function and call *that* function.

---

Further reading: [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming).